# Does this theorem hold for Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis

> Theorem.
>
> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space.
>
> Let $T:H\rightarrow H$ be an invertible operator.
>
> Let $S:H\rightarrow H$ be a bounded operator such that $||S-T||\cdot ||T^{-1}|| < 1$.
>
> Then, $S$ is invertible.

Does this theorem still hold for a banach space $X$ rather than a Hilbert space $H$?

Under given hypotheses, it can be shown that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\delta ||x|| ≦ ||Sx||$ for all $x$ and $S$ is injective. Hence, $S$ is closed injective operator. Is $S$ necessarily surjective in this case? If so, how do I prove that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $\|u\|<1$, then $\mathrm{id}+u$ is invertible with inverse $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^nu^n\,.$$ This relation holds in any unital Banach algebra, in particular the unital Banach algebra of endomorphisms of a Banach space. Thus, $S=T+(S-T)=T(\mathrm{id}+T^{-1}(S-T))$ is invertible as soon as $\|T^{-1}(S-T)\|<1$. But $\|T^{-1}(S-T)\|\leq\|T^{-1}\|\cdot\|S-T\|$, so your hypothesis guarantees invertibility of $S$.